# Why isn't the mic volume and receiving volume working?

Tags: audio, skype, microphone

When I join a group call, host a group call, or call the Echo/Sound Test Service my mic starts to increase in volume as I speak and the volume of my friends is maxed out. I can't lower it.

The problem appereared after I updated skype around 2 months ago. I've been looking around on the internet for a way to resolve the problem but I can't find a working solution.

I have disabled all windows mic-enhancements and I have disabled Skype mic and volume auto-adjust. I also have the latest version of skype. I have installed all the latest windows updates. I have tested my mic in other programs and it seems to work just fine. Same for the volume. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have left out a lot of details we need to help you. Please [edit] your question with the answers to the following; Have you done any research on this? Tried any other programs that use the microphone to see if the problem exists there also (if not this would indicate it is a Skype problem)? All Windows updates and Skype updates installed? Did it work before?